# Multiple domains on one database and CakePHP ACL Permissions

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, crud

**The situation**

We are developing a CakePHP webshop application that offers us the possibility to use just one database for different domains. For example we have shop1.com, shop2.com and shop3.com all on different domains that all use the same database. Customers see different shops, but we can maintain them and process orders from one back-end.

**Problem**

We are encountering a problem with the ACL-system in CakePHP. We would like to be able to set permissions for specific stores, so for example user 'Roger' has no access to the 'admin_edit' page on **store 1** but he does have permission to the 'admin_edit' page at **store 2**.

Each store is indentified with an unique store-ID in Config/bootstrap.php.

**Possible solutions**

I already tried to add a field named store_id to the acos_aros table. This would fix the problem because permissions are then dependent on the store the actions are made from. But how do I check for the store_id in this database in the most clean way? Without making changes in the CakePHP core..

**The facts**

- We're using CakePHP 2.2.3
- We have one central database containing all products, users, etc.
- We have different domains (applications) on several servers, all shops (3 at the moment) are indentified with a unique store_id which is set in Config/bootstrap.php.
- We are using CRUD-authorize.
- We would like to set permissions not only for each controller/action but also for each store. Otherwise, all administrators at store 1 have access to store 2 as well.

Comment: Are you opposed to using something other than ACL?

Comment: No, that's absolutely no problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: I would use Roles and then a HABTM between users and sites - something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to your problem on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886916/cakephp-one-core-one-app-one-databsse-multiple-domains-multiple-themes/17887614#17887614). The solution requires a domain router and after you have a set value for the domain you are on (domain.id). You can then restrict the access of certain data in various controllers. Integrate that with the ACL in cakephp.