# CakePHP One Core, One App, One Database, Multiple Domains & Multiple Themes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am a new addition to the world of CakePHP, and have only created / followed the blog tutorial, and extended it with users. I have been reading the 2.0 book to become more familiar with the framework.

Before I commit to moving to CakePHP, I have a couple of questions.

Currently, I develop a multi domain / multi theme CMS system which is procedural PHP. By doing this I have been able to create a single system on a single database with multiple domains and themes.

I take the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and look it up in a table of "brands" and then return a brand_id and theme directory. I then suffix all my SQL queries with "and brand_id = X".

I am looking to move over to Cake as the current platform has become overwhelming in size and complexity.

So in short...

Can I create an application with One Core, One App, One Database that can serve Multiple Domains and Themes?

Would I use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to look up the domain and return back a brand_id and theme?

I don't really want to have multiple databases, as if we had a large number of customers making changes across all databases could prove time consuming.

I certainly don't want to have multiple controllers and multiple models, but in some cases we would want a bespoke view if a customer had a specific requirement.

Any guidance on a basic configuration to get me started would be great. Would each Model "belong to" a "brand"? How would you "serve" up a brand?

```
Name: Brand1 Domain: www.brand1.com ThemeDir: Brand1
Name: Brand2 Domain: www.brand2.com ThemeDir: Brand2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation in which I am using wildcard subdomains. I accomplished this by doing a combination of things.

1. In my bootstrap file I am reading in my subdomain and assigning it a value to the cakePHP cache. In my case I am calling:

   `Configure::write('SubdomainHTTP', $myvalue);`

This would be your domain name in your case.

1. I am loading in my routes.php file a filename called subdomainRoute.php. This file checks to make sure that the route or subdomain in my case exists in the database. It concludes by writing the subdomain name and theme name using Configure::write like step 1.

   `App::uses('SubdomainRoute', 'Routes');`
2. I glue it all together here, in my AppController.php I read the information I write in step 2. Specifically the theme name and set it using:

   `$this->theme = $yourtheme;`

This should allow you to have different domain name themes. Given you will have to have a database to hold a list of domain names and there theme names.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback that is very helpful. How do you handle the SQL queries? In my case I see this being...

Select * from Users where username = "abc" and user_brand_id = 10;

How do you specify the brand_id to segregate the data?

Comment: each domain name "xy.com" would have a brand "mybrand" which the brand would be the theme. I would just put this in one table, don't bother with associations. Unless you can find a way to justify needing a association. The "xy.com" could be looked up by using php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: Sorry I don't think I have been clear enough. Inside the single database I would have multiple brands contents. So in a posts table I would have posts specifically for Brand1 and then some specifically for Brand2 and so on. So what I need to know is, once I have identified the brand and therefore brand_id how I could use that in a posts table. Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand sort of. I assume brand1 and brand2 have specific themes you are wanting? If so I would do this. In the beforefilter of the posts controller read in the configure::write value (the brand_id) which has been preloaded. You can then load only associated data from the posts table in your posts controller by referencing your brand_id which has been set in the beforefilter. Hopefully I am understanding correctly

Comment: That sounds about right. So Brand1 has a theme called Brand1Theme which I can set per your code. Could you give me a code example of how to use the beforeFilter with a brand_id to use it in a Posts Controller? Thanks

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller Just add the configure:read to the before filter

Comment: Ok, I have followed all of the above, and this is where I am at. I have basically written a Brand.ID configuration variable and then am using this in the Posts controller as a condition. It's not what you have suggested, but I am not really sure how I would use the beforeFilter. Here is the code.

public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all', array(
          'conditions' => array('Post.brand_id' => Configure::read('Brand.ID', 1)))));
    }

Comment: Would you say that is an acceptable approach? Can it be done in a better way?

Comment: looks good to me, make sure to add a case to assure the brand.id exists. if not throw a exception http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp