# Cakephp 1core, 1app, multiple domains

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The idea is to have one system that multiple domains can run off of.  Each domain can add entries to 1db, but not be able to see anything that isn't owned by them.  I've looked all over on how to solve this but it's beyond my current understanding.  Can anyone tell me what I should be looking for, or point me to a link that shows how to implement something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [One CakePHP library for multiple eCommerce Sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929127/one-cakephp-library-for-multiple-ecommerce-sites)

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution, but it is using a database to control the theme as well. Take a look at this: [CakePHP One Core, One App, One Database, Multiple Domains & Multiple Themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886916/cakephp-one-core-one-app-one-databsse-multiple-domains-multiple-themes/17887614#17887614)

You can use a database that holds rows of the current domains, the prerouting (which I call subdomain routing in my other post) would then allow you to set a alternate database prior to the rest of the application firing off. You would thus have 1 database (call it master) with all domains that are using your single app, and then X number of separate databases for each domain entry in the master database.